# Rails 4 - Kendo UI ImageBrowser successful upload but undefined thumbnail

Tags: image, upload, ruby-on-rails-4, kendo-ui, undefined

I am integrating Kendo UI editor with my custom CMS in Rails 4. Everything seems to work except a bug after a new image is uploaded. 
After I choose the image to upload the ImageBrowser adds a new item and displays the "upload in progress" circle. First it shows the image's file name near the circle, then it changes to undefined. 
[image: Undefined bug in Kendo ImageBrowser]

But if I close the ImageBrowser then open it again, the thumbnail is there as expected, without an error. If I artificially produce an error in the controller, at the end of the create action, then an error popup appears in the Kendo ImageBrowser (with 404 or 500), and if I wait a bit before clicking on the ok button then after clicking on it the thumbnail is there as expected also.

*So I guess 2 things:*

1. I am not providing the correct/expected response for the ImageBrowser at the end of the create action. (tried to render the same json as I render for transport.read but the problem still occurs). ***In this case my question is: What kind of response does Kendo ImageBrowser expect?***
2. It takes time to upload/process/resize the image and kendo asks too soon (so it gets an "undefined" result), and won't "ask" again.
   ***In this case my question is: How/when to delay or call read again to display the newly uploaded image's thumbnail correctly, without getting undefined back?***

Any suggestions to fix this? Or is it an error on Kendo UI side?

**Heres snippet from the output:**

```
Started POST "/kezelo/assets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-17 18:09:33 +0100
Processing by Kezelo::AssetsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa78bb00b00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/90/wjyhxjfs3gz3xkhsk8z_sz2w0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140117-49102-5lwwh4>, @original_filename="100_3048.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"100_3048.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "path"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"sdKhe348x26hm0k8kirzHlYgmH1LN73wf3ZWyOA5PHY="}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "assets" ("created_at", "image_file_size", "kendo_type", "photo", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 17 Jan 2014 17:09:35 UTC +00:00], ["image_file_size", 247716], ["kendo_type", "f"], ["photo", "100_3048.JPG"], ["updated_at", Fri, 17 Jan 2014 17:09:35 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.6ms)  commit transaction
  Asset Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "assets".* FROM "assets"
Completed 200 OK in 1416ms (Views: 29.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)


Started GET "/uploads/assets/undefined" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-17 18:09:35 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/assets/undefined"):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (4.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (47.9ms)
```

**My transport read url is (with dataType: json):**

```
http://localhost:3000/kezelo/assets
```

**The json output for the above url:**

```
[{"id":21,"name":"MAP_0528.JPG","type":"f","size":573896},{"id":22,"name":"MAP_0565.JPG","type":"f","size":646608},{"id":24,"name":"MAP_0667.JPG","type":"f","size":370408},{"id":26,"name":"mami_a_kertben.JPG","type":"f","size":364433},{"id":28,"name":"15kg_os.jpg","type":"f","size":975517},{"id":29,"name":"MAP_0257.jpg","type":"f","size":357723},{"id":31,"name":"DSC_0113.JPG","type":"f","size":574744},{"id":33,"name":"DSC_0062.JPG","type":"f","size":287631},{"id":34,"name":"100_2997.JPG","type":"f","size":126418},{"id":35,"name":"100_2999.JPG","type":"f","size":364433},{"id":36,"name":"100_3002.JPG","type":"f","size":340892},{"id":37,"name":"100_3025.JPG","type":"f","size":199709},{"id":38,"name":"100_3005.JPG","type":"f","size":435145},{"id":39,"name":"100_3019.JPG","type":"f","size":152869},{"id":40,"name":"100_3033.JPG","type":"f","size":208811},{"id":41,"name":"100_3039.JPG","type":"f","size":264420},{"id":42,"name":"100_3048.JPG","type":"f","size":247716}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. My first guess was right. I didn't provide the appropriate response for Kendo ImageBrowser.
It needed ONLY the uploaded image data in json format like this:

```
{"name":"new_image_name","type":"f","size":646608}
```

Now it works like a charm!
The most tricky thing of this integration was to provide a suitable json output for Kendo. For those who would like to use this editor in their apps, look into the acts_as_api gem. It will ease your pain.